# Emacs org mode: how can I filter on tags and todo status simultaneously?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using org mode's agenda function (keyboard short cut: C-c a ) in order to make different sorted views of all my tasks. I do this by defining the variable `org-agenda-custom-commands`. If I have the following code in my init file:

`(setq org-agenda-custom-commands'(
    ("p" "Projects" tags "PROJECT")
    ))`

I can filter out tasks with the tag "PROJECT" by using the shortcut `C-c a p`. Likewise I can use the code:

`(setq org-agenda-custom-commands'(
    ("t" "tasks to be done" tags-todo "TODO=\"TODO\" ")
    ))`

to filter out task with todo status equal to `TODO` by using the shortcut `C-c a t`. My question is, how can I define `org-aganda-custom-commands` to filter out tasks with todo status equal to `TODO` AND with a tag equal to `PROJECT` ?

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Are you able to achieve the view you want using the advanced searching techniques mentioned in the manual?  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  If so, then it is just a question of figuring out the arguments you need to pass to the relevant function -- e.g., `org-tags-view`.  You may also be interested in the `org-agenda-skip-function`:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html  Instead of keyboard shortcuts to refer to functions, you should probably familiarize yourself with the function names.

Comment: No, I am not able to achieve the view I want. That is my question. How do I make a view that filter out tasks with status TODO and tag PROJECT?

Comment: Try evaluating this in a `*Scratch*` buffer and see if that generates the type of result you are looking for:  `(org-tags-view t "project")`  The *first* argument in the function `org-tags-view` is whether to limit the search to only TODO entries -- the *second* argument is what to match.  You can evaluate the expression by placing the cursor to the right of the closing parentheses and typing `C-x C-e` *or* you can type `M-x eval-expression RET (org-tags-view t "project") RET`

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) However: (1) Your answer is not a way to maniplate the `org-agenda-custom-command`, which is what I would like to do. Is it possible to combine `tags` and `tags-todo` ? The following code does not work:
`(setq org-agenda-custom-commands'(
    ("x" "List Non-done projects" tags-todo "TODO=\"DONE\" " tags "PROJECT")`
    ))

(2) Where can I read about the `org-tags-view` variable? Typing `C-h v org-tags-view` gives me "No match" as a result. Why?

Comment: `org-tags-view` is a function, not a variable.  You can check the help with `C-h f org-tags-view`.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `tag` search view is poorly named.  It actually searches tags and properties.  `tag-todo` adds an extra condition that only matches todo headlines.  Use "+" to indicated that a condition is required (and "-" that it's forbidden).  So `+PROJECT+TODO=\"TODO\"` will match headlines with the tag `:PROJECT:` and a todo keyword of `TODO`.  Putting into a custom command looks like

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" "List Non-done projects"
          tags "+PROJECT+TODO=\"TODO\"")))
```

Comment: Thanks, very informative answer :) But why is there an asymetri here. We have to write `TODO=\"TODO\"`, but we do not have to write `tag=\"PROJECT\"`. That would be more logical, wouldn't it? Could I use the `tag`search to filter out tasks with a single special word inside the non-heading text and not only text in tags?

Comment: I guess the thinking is that the default is to match tags and to match anything else you have to give the property; your version does seem more logical..  To match non-heading/property text, maybe a `search` command would work better?

Comment: If I exchanged `tags` in your code with `tags-todo` would the code still function?

Comment: I think it would (`tags-todo` just restricts to search to todo headlines).  There's only one way to be sure....

Comment: @myotis, the TODO in the search spec is the name of the TODO keyword.  You can actually match on other TODO states:  +PROJECT+TODO=\"WAITING\" or +PROJECT+TODO=\"DONE\"

Comment: There's also a shortcut syntax of `tags "PROJECT/TODO"` which is the same as `tags "+PROJECT+TODO=\"TODO\""`.

Comment: How to exclude a todo keyword in this case (using with tags)?

Comment: You can exclude any todo keyword by matching against a regular expression: `-TODO="{.*}"`